# QML - How to fit and align items of GridView?

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

I want to fit all rectangles into `GridView`. I didn't use `GridLayout` because when I remove a rectangle from the `GridLayout`, they aligns again with `GridLayout`.
So I used `GridView` and my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
  visible: true
  width: 420
  height: 720
  title: qsTr("Hello World")


  GridView {
    id: area

    // If device orientation is vertical, GridView shall be 4x(model/4)
    property int verticalChoice: (parent.width < parent.height) ? 4 : 10
    //If device orientation is horizontal, GridView shall be (model/(model/4))x4
    property int horizontalChoice: (parent.width > parent.height) ? 10 : 4

    width: cellWidth * verticalChoice
    height: cellHeight * horizontalChoice
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    cellWidth: (parent.width / verticalChoice)
    cellHeight: (parent.height / horizontalChoice)

    model: 40
    clip: true
    interactive: false

    delegate: Rectangle {
      id: rect
      width: area.cellWidth - 5
      height: area.cellHeight - 5
      color: 'red'
      Text {
        text: index
        color: 'white'
        anchors.centerIn: parent
      }
      MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: rect.destroy(1000)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I set `model` of `GridView` as `40` and I set `interactive` as `false`. But I see just `15` items like this:
[image: image.png]
Also I wrote `anchors.centerIn: parent` but it didn't run. How can I do them (to fit and align)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the number of items you simply have an error in the assignment of `horizontalChoice`, setting a 4*4 grid instead of a 10*4:

```
property int verticalChoice: (parent.width < parent.height) ? 4 : 10
property int horizontalChoice: (parent.width < parent.height) ? 10 : 4
```

For the centering issue, `anchors.centerIn: parent` is actually working as expected but since you specified the delegates to be 5px smaller than the `cellWidth`/`cellWidth`, you have a 5px empty space on the right and bottom.

To prevent that, you can use a wrapping `Item` (As far as I know `GridView` does not have any `spacing` property):

```
delegate: Item {
    width: area.cellWidth
    height: area.cellHeight
    Rectangle {
        color: 'red'
        anchors {
            fill: parent
            margins: 5
        }

        Text {
            text: index
            color: 'white'
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, it is true. Well, why does `anchors.centerIn: parent` not run?

Comment: I edited my code like your code: gist.github.com/anonymous/9f219711985f8c69831ece5a7a02ab0f But it's not working.